# Changing Host for website, moved all data but website goes blank after DB import - Worrdpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I am changing host for my website and it contains a lot of data. I moved all the data in my domain folder under Public_html directory and then imported all of the DB from PhpMyAdmin. Before importing the database it was showing twenty thirteen theme and Hello world post but after importing it just shows a blank page without giving any error. Although the /wp-admin URL works fine. One time i used the WP Backup plugin and made a DB backup with it and it worked also but it is not working now, i've tried several times. Also I've tried importing every table in my DB and left the wp_options and it worked but the settings weren't there and also when i try to change the theme it again shows the same error.

Please guys help, because i've been charged $2/day by my new host and my website isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

**use [Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin to move your site from one host to another**

Comment: That is the complete answer ?

Comment: no i guess i would have copy and pasted the description part of the plugin in here

Answer (score 0):

A. You must go to the admin and activate your theme again ..

B. Verify for the settings blog_url and home_url

In general - For exporting / moving a site there is really nothing to it , you just need to :

1 . move all your folder structure .

2 . Change `wp-config` . Put all correct DB info ( pass, user, ip, db name ) . SALT optional. don´t forget wp_ `prefix` ..

3 . go to phpmydmin , import the old DB on a blank one .

and then run these :

```
/**
To update WordPress options with the new blog location, use the following SQL command:
**/

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

/**
After that you will need to fix URLs of the WordPress posts and pages, which translated from post slug, and stored in database wp_posts table as guid field. The URL values in this field are stored as abolute URLs instead of relative URLs, so it needs to be changed with the following SQL query:
**/

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');

/**
If you have linked internally within blog posts or pages with absolute URLs, these links will point to wrong locations after you move the blog location. Use the following SQL commands to fix all internal links to own blog in all WordPress posts and pages:
**/

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Then verify for the settings `blog_url` and `home_url` in `wp_options`- and you are done.

If you have followed the above correctly - the site will be on and OK wordpress-wise.

Note: do not forget to update the `wp-config` DB settings including wp_prefix ( also update in SQL )

Comment: But I've already tried doing that but it still gives the same error of blank page. Any more suggestions because today is the last day my previous hosting is going to expire.

Comment: Have you reactivated your theme ??? if you do all the above correctly - there is no reason it should not work. on 99% of the cases if you have blank page , and admin is available , then you must activate theme ( and re - configure menus, widgets plugins etc..) but that also means you imported wrongly .

Comment: Yes, I've reactivated the theme and the error only appears after i reactivate the theme. And also while uploading the previous DB in phpmyadmin error occurs while uploading wp_options while every other table uploads successfully.

Comment: You must have some error in the DB or files. I suggest you upload everything again , drop the whole DB and start over . No one can guess what actions / errors you previously did to correct them now.Did you also upgraded a version ( that´s a no-no)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "upgraded a version"? And i've done exactly as i did before but it's not working. I don't know why?

Comment: 1 - `upgrade version` means did you used a different WP version when moving the site . 2 - If you indeed do all the phases I listed - it would have worked. I do it on a daily basis. and.. 3 - http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Towelday-Innsbruck.jpg

Comment: No, i don't, I've the same wordpress running on the previous host as my new host. And, I've many plugins activated on my previous website but don't have one on the new one. Do you think that could be the reason WP_options is causing the error.

Comment: So . Like I said - you `did not` follow the above steps like you say . You need to upload the exact same folder structure . and then import the DB on a clean one . It will work ..

Comment: Thanks Obmerk Kronen for the support. Everuthing is fine now and its working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can sometimes be caused outside of wordpress, it could be a php error. But before you get to that try these few extra ideas:

Re-save your permalinks in wordpress, do this by picking another setting and then the one you were originally using.

set WP_DEBUG mode to TRUE in your wp-config.php, this will output any errors to your page.

Disable any plugins, cache plugins can cause problems like this.

Check your server php log for any errors.